# How to integrate CD with CircleCI?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, continuous-delivery

I've been following a lot of tutorials on CI using Python but the tutorials seem to stop there and rarely take the next step to CD. I'm a sole developer as well.

I've setup a project on Github that runs locally on my PC and is not a web app. I've connected it to CircleCI for CI. Here is my `config.yml` file.

```
  version: 2
  jobs:
    build:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/python:3.7

      working_directory: ~/repo

      steps:
        # Step 1: obtain repo from GitHub
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: install dependencies
            command: |
              sudo apt-get update
              pip install -r requirements.txt
        - run:
            name: run tests
            command: |
              python -m pytest -v
```

Everything runs great and I get an email from CircleCI alerting me the build failed when I make a push to master on github and one the of the pytests fail.

So my question, is what is the next step here? I have a few thoughts but am not sure on any of them honestly.

1. Create separate test and prod versions of the code. Automate updating the prod version when the test version builds with no errors. However, not sure what tools to use for this.
2. Push to project to Dockerhub. This seems redundant to me though, because Docker would run the same pytests that CircleCI is running. I'm not sure how this would even help with CD at this point.

Could someone please provide some guidance on next steps here?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have only one job `build`, so you can add more jobs under the jobs section. So what you want to do here is:

1. add test
2. build prod version
3. Push to Dockerhub

Please use config 2.1 to enable the workflows.

```
version: 2.1
  jobs:
    build:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/python:3.7

      working_directory: ~/repo

      steps:
        # Step 1: obtain repo from GitHub
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: install dependencies
            command: |
              sudo apt-get update
              pip install -r requirements.txt
        - run:
            name: run tests
            command: |
              python -m pytest -v

    test:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/python:3.7
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "do your test here"

    build-prod:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/python:3.7
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "build your app"

    push-to-dockerhub:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/python:3.7
      steps:
        - checkout
        - setup_remote_docker # this is necessary to use docker daemon
        - run: echo "do docker login and docker push here"

workflows:
  build-and-push:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test
          requires:
            - build
      - build-prod
          requires:
            - test
      - push-to-dockerhub
          requires:
            - build-prod
```

Please make sure we're using `requires` to run the job only when the required job is finished successfully.

Well definitely I've not tested the config on my end, but it's like above config. You have more configuration documents here - so please take a look for it to make it perfectly work.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have just a couple questions if you don't mind. 1) There's no build per say in Python, so would it be correct to omit this? 2) Is the continuation of this having a webhook on the Dockerhub that automatically downloads the code to PROD if a successful push is made to Dockerhub?

Comment: You can change your image as your need - not sure if it's you're asking. Just change the config and validate with circleci cli. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/ You don't need to push to trigger the build to validate your config. I'm not sure what you want to do for #2 as well..